# How to insert missing years in temporary table in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I work with Sales and problem is that this table does not have records for each client for every year. Records are missing randomly. Instead i need to have those years there and put 0 for sales for those years for my analysis.

I have limited knowledge of SQL. Can anybody help on this one? What i have as of now and what i would like to have is shown below.

I have thoughts to use LAG() function, but missing records can be for 2 years in a row or 3. I am not sure how to tackle such problem.

What I have now:

| Client_ID | SalesYear | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 12 |
| 1 | 2012 | 20 |
| 1 | 2013 | 21 |
| 1 | 2016 | 14 |

What i need to have:

| Client_ID | SalesYear | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 12 |
| 1 | 2011 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012 | 20 |
| 1 | 2013 | 21 |
| 1 | 2014 | 0 |
| 1 | 2015 | 0 |
| 1 | 2016 | 14 |

Answer (score 1):

You need a complete list of years to outer-join with.

You can do this a number of ways, the basic principle would be:

```
with y as (
  select * from (values(2010),(2011),(2012),(2013),(2014),(2015),(2016))y(y)
)
insert into t (Client_Id, SalesYear, Sales)
select 1, y.y, 0
from y
where not exists (select * from t where t.SalesYear = y.y);
```

Comment: Hello Guys! Danile G and Stu thank you all for such quick answers! However, can it be done by using something simpler like Joins or CASE statement?

Comment: by the way i work in the range from 2010 through 2022 only. So the range is limited regarding how many years can be at maximum there if it helps. Also, i work with temporary table can all that code be used with temporary tables too? Thanks!

Comment: As Stu mentioned, there are many approaches to this, but I think you’ll still want the OUTER JOIN concept he referenced, whereby you have a fixed set of years from 2010 to now (a table or CTE with a single row for each year) and use that as your primary pull. Then, left join over to tables to get your final query, such as the clients table, sales table, etc. His example and mine should both work well with temporary tables or table variables.

Comment: Yes you can apply this to temp tables - and this is basically a join, the exists operator in this case is still a (semi) join and more performant than a left-outer join because the optimizer can filter rows before fully joining both inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE
(Client_ID int, SalesYear int, Sales money)

INSERT INTO @Sales(Client_ID, SalesYear, Sales) SELECT 1, 2010, 12 
INSERT INTO @Sales(Client_ID, SalesYear, Sales) SELECT 1, 2012, 20 
INSERT INTO @Sales(Client_ID, SalesYear, Sales) SELECT 1, 2013, 21 
INSERT INTO @Sales(Client_ID, SalesYear, Sales) SELECT 1, 2016, 14;



with years as 
(
    select 2000 as theYear 
    UNION ALL
    select y.theYear + 1 as theYear
    from years y
    where y.theYear + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)

select 
    Y.theYear, S.Client_ID, S.Sales
FROM 
    Years Y
LEFT JOIN
    @Sales S ON S.SalesYear = Y.theYear
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

You can change "2000" to something more appropriate.

Comment: I used your code and it give me "Parse error at line ... Incorrect syntax near 'maxrecursion' I use code before your 'with' statement to put what i need from DB to temporary table. What can be wrong what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to put a semi-colon at the end of the line right before this code. For example, like I did in the last insert statement in the sample data table.

Comment: Good day, DanielG! Thank you for your input. I ran ' SELECT * FROM #TABLE_2; ' and then your code above and SQL Server gives me 'Parse error... Incorrect syntax near 'maxrecursion''. I do not understand what is wrong...Can you help on that please?

Comment: Are you doing this in a VIEW, stored procedure, etc.?

Comment: Good day, DanielG! Thank you for giving a helping hand! I use #[name of table] to store my results. So this is temporary database as far as i understand. The reason i am doing this is because i do not need to change anything in the original database. Also, off the topic can you recommend good book or course for SQL Server if possible? How did you learn SQL?

Comment: In my example I use a table variable (@Sales) and then insert rows. You can do the same (instead of a temp table) and pull from actual tables in your DB. Run it in as is in SSMS and it should work for you.  I was on the BETA team of MSFT Access 1.0 decades ago and it obfuscated SQL for me (i.e. I could create a query graphically). Eventually I needed more power, so used SQL. I’m sure there are tons of good books, but I would start with the basics of relational theory for design concept, then move into basic SQL syntax (SELECT, INSERT, etc.). Design concepts first, then the language!